# Apache RewriteRule and slashes (%2F)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^like/(.+)$ ask.php/$1
```

Which works just fine for requests like:

```
/like/someting+here/something+else
```

But for requests where one of the path parts contains an escaped slash (`%2F`), the server spits out a 404 Not Found error:

```
/like/one%2Ftwo+things/
```

Is there any way to fix this? I tried both `[B]` and `[NE]` flags (separate and together) but nothing worked.

**Edit:** I also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^like/ ask.php
# or
RewriteRule ^like/(.*) ask.php
```

So that it doesn't necessarily have to match the slash. It's still not working.

Comment: Is there a directory path, using your example, called "/like/one/two+things/" where "two+things" is a subdirectory of "one" which is a subdriectory of "like"? If not, you can't have filenames (at least in Unix) with a slash in them and I'd be willing to bet that if Apache allows an escaped slash there's a potential security issue.

Comment: No, there's no such path. But I don't see why it matters, since it should be internally rewritten to `ask.php/$1`, so there's no security issue :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apache directive helped me

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer here [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3279075.htm). To quote the relevant bits:

> The naked "%2f" is allowed in a query string. but not in a URL. In order to be valid, it would have to be encoded as %252f, which I think you will find to work as you expect.
>
> Because the URL is itself invalid, the server is rejecting it before any apache modules are invoked.
>
> For more information, see [RFC2396 - Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html).